# Использование в дополнительных полях wordpress кода php

Tags: wordpress

Имеются дополнительные поля "Заголовок h1" (input) и поле Html-код (textarea).

Дополнительные поля в коде темы выводятся так:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true); ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'htmlkod', true); ?>
```

Допустим я ввел в поле "Html-код (textarea)" следующий код:

```
<p>Заголовок страницы на которой вы находитесь: Огнетушители</p>
```

Он спокойно отработает и выведет эту информацию.

Но если я ввожу такой код:

```
<p>Заголовок страницы на которой вы находитесь: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true); ?></p>
```

То он не обрабатывается в коде. Получается такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как можно осуществить подобное? Возможно ли вообще?

Comment: Возможно, но это будет дыра. Переделывай поля так, что бы не пришлось вставлять php-код. Как вариант - сделай шорткод, который уже можно вставить в поле.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, буду копать в этом направлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно ли вообще? Наверное. Надо ли? Нет 100%.

**Не лучший вариант**

Если же требуется через поля вставлять какое-то значение, которые будет меняться в зависимости от того, на какой страннице находится пользователь, то можно попробовать использовать что-то типа шаблона в вашем поле htmlkod:

```
<p>Заголовок страницы на которой вы находитесь: %header%</p>
```

Тогда в шаблоне вывод уже можно будет сделать примерно так:

```php
$header = str_replace('%header%', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true), get_post_meta($post->ID, 'htmlkod', true)); //То есть в строке с вашим HTML-кодом заменяем своего рода shortcode %header% на то, что вернёт функция get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true)
echo $header; //Там, где вам нужно
```

**Вариант получше**

Но, как отметил @SeVlad (ему отдельное спасибо!), такой вариант не самый лучший (хотя, пожалуй, в рамках конкретно данного вопроса и неплох).

И если обратиться к поисковику с вопросом по типу "shortcode wordpress", то можно выяснить, что в Wordpress имеется возможность создавать свои shortcode с помощью функции `add_shortcode`. И уже применяя её к решению данного вопроса, можно сделать что-то типа такого (не знаю, что у автора означает `$post->ID`, но скорее всего идентификатор текущей записи в цикле. А значит код получения заголовка `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true)` используем напрямую):

```php
add_shortcode('my_shortcode_header_current_page', 'my_shortcode_output_header_page_func');

function my_shortcode_output_header_page_func($atts, $content, $shortcode_tag) {
    global $post;
    return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true);
}
```

В этом случае уже вся дальнейшая работа лежит на самом Wordpress. То есть в любом месте контента, где встретиться `[my_shortcode_header_current_page]`, будет выводиться заголовок, указанный в соответствующем поле.
Данный код можно расположить в файле functions.php вашей темы.

P.S. Можно усовершенствовать shortcode, добавив ему атрибуты. Но всё это можно найти в документации к вышеуказаннолй функции.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ, это то что мне было нужно. Все работает!

Comment: @ToneR это плохое решение. Во первых это может создавать нагрузку, а во вторых употребление таких кастомых шаблонизаторов (%xxxx%<) - это бедпрактик. Уж лучше шорткод, это хотя бы родное.

Comment: @SeVlad, с вашего позволения чуть улучшил ответ. Также думаю, что автору (или нам у автора) стоило уточнить, что, где и как это всё у него используется, чтобы предложить, возможно, самый наилучший в его ситуации вариант. Но, наверное, и этого хватит.

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, О, это уже лучше. Плюс за правильное понимание критики :) (А вообще в данном конкретном случае наверняка не нужно ничего такого. Нужно просто поправить шаблон где выводится поле. Да и вообще *такое* поле может и не нужно вовсе)

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, SeVlad, благодарю Вас за подсказки. Потребовалось такое решение, так как требуется на разных страницах вручную менять html код, именно поэтому заинтересовался таким вопросом. Теперь касаемо шорткода, код который Вы мне подсказали я вставил в functions.php своей темы, если использовать так:

return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'H1', true);

То так не работает, но если делаю вот так:

return '111';

То шорт код выводит "111", а почему-то get_post_meta не срабатывает. В чем проблема может быть?

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, не срабатывает идентификатор текущей записи в цикле $post->ID, если указать id записи вручную - то выводится

Comment: Нашел решение, срабатывает если в функцию my_shortcode_output_header_page_func добавить global $post;

Comment: @ToneR Верно! Как-то забыл об этом :(